# Using spork on windows in jruby on rails throws an exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, spork

I followed the rails tutorial on http://ruby.railstutorial.org. When I try running

```
bundle exec spork
```

I'm getting following error:

> Using RSpec, Unknown (Java::JavaLang::IllegalArgumentException).

Running just

```
spork
```

gives me the same error.

Running either bundle exec spork --boostrap or spork --bootstrap gives me next lines:

Using RSpec, Unknown

Running RSpec works fine. bundle exec spork --bootstrap also works.

Trace:

```
Using RSpec, Unknown
 (Java::JavaLang::IllegalArgumentException)
java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:69)
java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
org.jruby.util.io.Java5ProcessMaker.start(Java5ProcessMaker.java:58)
org.jruby.util.ShellLauncher.buildProcess(ShellLauncher.java:466)
org.jruby.util.ShellLauncher.popenShared(ShellLauncher.java:710)
org.jruby.util.ShellLauncher.popenShared(ShellLauncher.java:689)
org.jruby.util.ShellLauncher.popenShared(ShellLauncher.java:685)
org.jruby.util.ShellLauncher.popen(ShellLauncher.java:669)
org.jruby.RubyIO.popen(RubyIO.java:3568)
org.jruby.RubyIO$s$0$1$popen.call(RubyIO$s$0$1$popen.gen:65535)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:211)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:207)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.DAsgnNode.interpret(DAsgnNode.java:110)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:374)
org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:347)
org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:304)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:130)
org.jruby.RubyDir.chdir(RubyDir.java:466)
org.jruby.RubyDir$s$0$1$chdir.call(RubyDir$s$0$1$chdir.gen:65535)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:211)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:322)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:178)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:187)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(CallOneArgBlockNode.java:60)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:117)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:190)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:199)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:147)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:183)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:86)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:216)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:120)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:212)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:207)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:322)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:178)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:182)
org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:813)
org.jruby.RubyClass$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$i$newInstance.gen:65535)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:266)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:117)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:190)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:199)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.CaseNode.interpret(CaseNode.java:138)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:147)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:183)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:63)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:276)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:231)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:352)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:237)
org.jruby.ast.CallThreeArgNode.interpret(CallThreeArgNode.java:61)
org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:216)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:120)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(ASTInterpreter.java:120)
org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:722)
org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:2479)
org.jruby.runtime.load.ExternalScript.load(ExternalScript.java:66)
org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.load(LoadService.java:270)
org.jruby.RubyKernel.loadCommon(RubyKernel.java:1070)
org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(RubyKernel.java:1052)
org.jruby.RubyKernel$s$0$1$load.call(RubyKernel$s$0$1$load.gen:65535)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:211)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:207)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
c_3a_.Program_20_Files.jruby_minus_1_dot_6_dot_6.lib.ruby.gems.$1_dot_8.bin.spork.__file__(c:/Program Files/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/spork:19)
c_3a_.Program_20_Files.jruby_minus_1_dot_6_dot_6.lib.ruby.gems.$1_dot_8.bin.spork.load(c:/Program Files/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/spork)
org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:695)
org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:688)
org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:595)
org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:444)
org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:344)
org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:256)
org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:222)
org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:206)
org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:186)
```